# onClick and AsyncTask Fatal Exception #1

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I use an Activity as a Dialog ( don't think there is a problem but I mention it ).

That Dialog gets some data from the user and then with `Apache's HttpClient` I send that data to a web service.
That means I've got a Button and an onClick() method associated with that Button.
When `onClick()` takes place I get and pass the data the user adds, to a method ( named it *sendJSON* ) that sends them as JSON.

Then I added the code for the Thread. I extended AsyncTask pass as parameters the data and inside `doInBackground` I call my *sendJSON* method and now inside onClick I just call `execute()` with the user data as parameters.

From what I have searched on Google the error is that I make a call to my Activity so I can then call the `sendJSON` method. 
And then is this :

```
Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread
```

So I got two questions. What is a quick fix for this problem? `runOnUiThread` inside onClick() method will do the work for me? 
And second what was wrong with my logic from the beginning? I started building the methods I need and then added the code for the Thread. So how I should have thought it from start?

It took me a lot of hours to think it, write the code and search to understand what is wrong so I just want to know what I should learn from that and don't repeat the same errors again.

Thank you

EDIT :  code

**onClick** :

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

       if( v == send ) {


            //Mocking data
            String  network="anetwork", password    , comment;
            String lat="1", longt="2";

            EditText passwd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
            password = passwd.getText().toString();

            EditText com = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.comment);
            comment = com.getText().toString();


            LongSend ls = new LongSend();
            ls.execute(lat,longt,network,password,comment);

         }
    }
```

**AsyncTask** :

```
public class LongSend extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params){
        Log.i("AsyncTask", "here 1");

        int param1 = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
        int param2 = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);

        DialogActivity da = new DialogActivity();
        try {
            da.sendJson(param1, param2, params[2], params[3], params[4]);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void nothing) {
        //              
    }

}
```

**sendJSON**

```
public void sendJson( int lat, int longt,  String network, String passwd, String comment )  throws JSONException {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("web_service_here");   
    HttpResponse response;

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject nested = new JSONObject();

        try { 
                Log.i("SENDJSON", " print");

                nested.put("lat", lat);
                nested.put("longt", longt);

                json.put("coord", nested);      //add "nested" to "json"

                json.put("network", network);
                json.put("password", passwd);
                json.put("comment", comment);

                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

                httppost.getParams().setParameter("json", json);

                Log.v("sendJSON", "json== " +json);

                httppost.setEntity(se);
                Log.v("sendJSON", "SE== " +se);

                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                if(response !=null) {

                        str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

                        Log.i("POST", "send JSON data");
                        Log.i("DATA", "Data Send==" +str );

                }

        } catch ( ClientProtocolException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( IOException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

**Activity**

```
public class DialogActivity  extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public static String str;
Button send;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_fragment);


    send =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);


}
```

**LogCat :**

> 06-08 05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask
>
> ## 1 06-08 05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>
> doInBackground() 06-08 05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266) 06-08 05:33:59.801:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(397):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>   06-08 05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   06-08 05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>   06-08 05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 06-08
>   05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
>   06-08 05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
>   06-08 05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397):    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020) 06-08 05:33:59.801:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(397): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't
>   create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>   06-08 05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397):    at
>   android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:121) 06-08 05:33:59.801:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(397):    at
>   android.app.Activity.(Activity.java:727) 06-08 05:33:59.801:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(397):    at
>   org.teo.wifit.DialogActivity.(DialogActivity.java:30) 06-08
>   05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at
>   org.teo.wifit.DialogActivity$LongSend.doInBackground(DialogActivity.java:88)
>   06-08 05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397):    at
>   org.teo.wifit.DialogActivity$LongSend.doInBackground(DialogActivity.java:1)
>   06-08 05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252) 06-08 05:33:59.801:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(397):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   06-08 05:33:59.801: E/AndroidRuntime(397):    ... 4 more

Line 88 where the problem is :   `DialogActivity da = new DialogActivity();`

Comment: please provide the code.

Comment: @amrinder007 code and Logcat added

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update/access ui from doInBackground(). You should update/access ui on the ui thread. You can use runOnUithread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Check the docs in the above link

You can do all your network related operation in doInBackground(params). The result of doInBackground(params) computation is parameter to onPostExecute(result).

doInBackground is invoked on the background thread. You can return result and based on the result you can update ui or display a dialog or message in onPostExecute.

Comment: Yes that's true I mentioned it in my Question too. So is `runOnUiThread` the best solution I can have or I can make some changes in my code so it can work with `AsyncTask` ?

Comment: @mt0s there is no need to create a new Dialogactivity. do your http operation in doinbackground. return boolean value. based on the boolean value you can display a message or dialog in onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do UI related operations in your background thread, any UI related work such as displaying or modifying must be done in main thread. So if u want to do those operations, use ActivityName.this.runOnUIThread() method or do your UI operations in onPostExecute